# Sidebar navigation is not visible in safari only

Tags: wordpress, browser, safari, navigation, compatibility

I am developing my portfolio site for wordpress and for some reason that I have not been able to identify my page links are not made visible in safari, but they work fine in all other tested browsers.

http://www.jcstudios.org/about/

They should be in the sidebar on the left side of the page, as you can see in firefox, chrome, i.e., etc, but not in safari. Does anybody know what may be causing this or have a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Portfolio, about and blog links? if so i see them in safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the sidebar in Safari 5. Try fixing your code errors in the sidebar and see if that works: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.jcstudios.org/about/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654

And use dev tools to see the three images that are 404ing:

```
about/images/close.png
about/images/loading.gif
wp-content/themes/images/header.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, there was an issue with the way wordpress was organizing the list of the pages that was causing the problem. I was able to correct it with this:

'<ul id="sitenav"><?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&exclude=346&depth=1'); ?></ul>'